# Getting an Invalid Syntax error using tkinter in python IDLE Shell

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Heres the code, please help

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_polygon(10, 10, 10, 60, 50, 35)
1
def movetriangle(event):
    canvas.move(1, 5, 0)
Canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Return>', movetriangle)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Its highlighting the C in Canvas.bind_all as invalid syntax. I'm trying to get the triangle to move when enter is pressed. Any help or alternate code would be appreciated. Im guessing the code needs altering for Canvas.bind_all to work or something needs to be imported for it to work.

Comment: Are you saving this code in a file and then running it - or are you typing it in line-by-line in the shell window?  In the later case, you have to terminate multi-line statements (such as your function definition) with a blank line, before you can type a new top-level statement; this restriction doesn't apply to script files, which are the normal way of running Python code.

Comment: yeah, typing it line by line in the shell, using a script file might have been a better way to do it, ill try what you said though, many thanks :), really appreciate it.

Comment: I did it from a saved file and it worked, thanks again, should've known that. I'm new to programming but love learning something new every day and learning from others. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the class name Canvas instead of the variable name canvas.
Also you must call tk.mainloop() to actually have your actions executed.
So try this:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_polygon(10, 10, 10, 60, 50, 35)

def movetriangle(event):
    canvas.move(1, 5, 0)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Return>', movetriangle)
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks vorrade, really appreciate it. You guys are really helpful. Am learning so much from you. :)

Comment: @programminglearner Happy to help. If you like someone's answer then you can mark the answer as useful. It helps them gain reputation.